# Relationship between execution time and response time of Durable functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, instance, azure-durable-functions

I implemented data analysis with Durable Functions so that it would be one function per instance.

Using VScode's Durable functions extension, the execution details are shown in the image.

[image]

The wait time between instances of "exploratory_data_analysis" to "decision_tree_regression" is short. However, the start of "random_forest" takes a considerable amount of time from the end of the previous function. This has resulted in a longer overall response time.

The long execution time of "random_forest" is unavoidable, but why does it take so long to start an instance?
The data being passed is the same as "redge_regression" etc., so it should not be overhead caused by transfer data.

Also, is the time represented by this extension the time from instance startup to return code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`random_forest`** function is started at the end because, It is the last activity to run after all the other previous activities. The Azure Durable Function will run activities according to the sequence of your code. By what I understand, random_forest is the last activity to run in your Durable Function, Thus it is showing at last. And the Time at the horizontal column represents the Time at which your Function is created or started till the last updated time or completion time.

I tried performing data analysis as similar as yours and below are my results:-

Reference- My [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77451020/transfer-format-for-durable-functions/77517542#)

**My function_app.py:-**

Make sure you are distributing the load in your code properly by calling the data more efficiently:-

```py
import pickle
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing  # Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso  
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error  # MSE(Mean Squared Error)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
### client function ###
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
    data = yield context.call_activity("prepare_data", '')
    simple = yield context.call_activity("simple_regression", {"data": data})
    multiple = yield context.call_activity("multiple_regression", {"data": data})
    exploratory_data_analysis =  yield context.call_activity("exploratory_data_analysis", {"data": data})
    data_processing = yield context.call_activity("multivariate_linear_regression", {"data": data})
    multivariate_linear_regression = yield context.call_activity("data_processing", {"data": data})
    ridge_regression =  yield context.call_activity("ridge_regression", {"data": data})
    k_nearest_neighbor =  yield context.call_activity("k_nearest_neighbor", {"data": data})
    decision_tree_regression = yield context.call_activity("decision_tree_regression", {"data": data})
    random_forest =  yield context.call_activity("random_forest", {"data": data})
    return "finished"

### activity function ###
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def prepare_data(blank: str):
    # prepare data
    california_housing = fetch_california_housing()
    exp_data = pd.DataFrame(california_housing.data, columns=california_housing.feature_names)
    print(exp_data.columns.tolist) # explanatory variables
    tar_data = pd.DataFrame(california_housing.target, columns=['HousingPrices']) # target variable
    data = pd.concat([exp_data, tar_data], axis=1) # merge data
    print("Column Names:")
    print(data.columns.tolist()) 
    # Delete anomalous values
    data = data[data['HouseAge'] != 52]
    data = data[data['HousingPrices'] != 5.00001]

    # Create useful variables
    data['Household'] = data['Population']/data['AveOccup']
    data['AllRooms'] = data['AveRooms']*data['Household']
    data['AllBedrms'] = data['AveBedrms']*data['Household']

    # Ensure 'MedInc' column doesn't contain null or missing values
    data = data.dropna(subset=['MedInc'])

    # Create a dictionary to store multiple data items
    prepared_data = {
        'data': data.to_dict(),
        'columns': data.columns.tolist(),
        'target_column': 'HousingPrices',
        'MedInc': data['MedInc'].tolist()  # Add 'MedInc' column to the dictionary as a list
    }
    return prepared_data

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def simple_regression(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Convert dictionary back to a DataFrame
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(arg['data'])

        # Handling missing or NaN values
        data.dropna(inplace=True)

        # Selecting the explanatory variable 'MedInc' and target 'HousingPrices'
        X_simple = data[['MedInc']]
        y = data[arg['target_column']]

        # Check lengths of X_simple and y
        if len(X_simple) != len(y):
            return "Lengths of X_simple and y do not match"

        # Initialize and fit the linear regression model
        simple_model = LinearRegression()
        simple_model.fit(X_simple, y)

        return {
            'model': simple_model,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"

### multiple regression analysis ###
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def multiple_regression(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Convert dictionary back to a DataFrame
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(arg['data'])

        # Handling missing or NaN values
        data.dropna(inplace=True)

        # Selecting multiple explanatory variables and target 'HousingPrices'
        X_multiple = data.drop(columns=[arg['target_column']])  # Drop the target column
        y = data[arg['target_column']]

        # Check lengths of X_multiple and y
        if len(X_multiple) != len(y):
            return "Lengths of X_multiple and y do not match"

        # Initialize and fit the multiple regression model
        multiple_model = LinearRegression()
        multiple_model.fit(X_multiple, y)

        return {
            'model': multiple_model,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"
    

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def exploratory_data_analysis(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Convert dictionary back to a DataFrame
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(arg['data'])

        # Perform exploratory data analysis tasks here
        # For example: summary statistics, visualizations, etc.

        # Placeholder - perform some EDA tasks here
        eda_result = "Exploratory Data Analysis performed"

        return {
            'result': eda_result,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"

### data processing ###
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def data_processing(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Placeholder - Add data processing steps here
        # This could involve data cleaning, normalization, etc.

        processed_data_result = "Data processing completed"

        return {
            'result': processed_data_result,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"
    
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def multivariate_linear_regression(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Placeholder - Implement Multivariate Linear Regression here
        # Use the processed data from 'arg' dictionary

        mlr_result = "Multivariate Linear Regression completed"

        return {
            'result': mlr_result,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"


### ridge regression ###
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def ridge_regression(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Placeholder - Implement Ridge Regression here

        ridge_result = "Ridge Regression completed"

        return {
            'result': ridge_result,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"

### k-nearest neighbor ###
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def k_nearest_neighbor(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Placeholder - Implement K-Nearest Neighbor here

        knn_result = "K-Nearest Neighbor completed"

        return {
            'result': knn_result,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"

### decision tree regression ###
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def decision_tree_regression(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Placeholder - Implement Decision Tree Regression here

        dt_result = "Decision Tree Regression completed"

        return {
            'result': dt_result,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"

### random forest ###
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="arg")
def random_forest(arg: dict):
    try:
        # Placeholder - Implement Random Forest here

        rf_result = "Random Forest completed"

        return {
            'result': rf_result,
            'status': 'success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"
```

In your scenario, The **random_forest** is taking a long time to start after previous activities are completed is also because of the heavy processing of the Function. ***If you are running this Function locally or in Function App, It will run the Function with the default Azure Storage account mentioned in the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string, If you want to run durable Function more efficiently you can add additional storage account for Durable Function*** like below:-

My **`local.settings.json` with additional `MyStorageAccountAppSetting`**:-

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=vsiddheshrg989173;AccountKey=xxxxxStOyfWOw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "MyStorageAccountAppSetting" : "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=silicon1;AccountKey=xxxxxaBKbO/PA+AStKWFvaQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

*You need to apply same settings in your Function App Enviroment variables.*

My **`host.json` containing `MyStorageAccountAppSetting`**:-

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "storageProvider": {
        "connectionStringName": "MyStorageAccountAppSetting"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also ***add concurrency limit setting***  for your **Activity Functions** to **increase the parallel execution of the Function and partition count mechanism** by specifying **partition count in** **host.json** file like:-

**host.json:-**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "storageProvider": {
        "connectionStringName": "MyStorageAccountAppSetting",
        "partitionCount": 3

        
      },
      "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 10,
      "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 10

    }
  }
}
```

The horizontal time is the **createdTime UTC** and **lastUpdatedTime UTC**:-

[image]

My random_forest activity is triggering properly with the below settings in my host.json:-

[image]

[image]

**I have referred these two Github Documents for host,json setting and refer these to get more insights on impoving performance of Azure Durable Functions:-**

1. [azure-docs/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale.md)
2. [azure-docs/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-azure-storage-provider.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-azure-storage-provider.md#orchestration-start-delays)

Comment: Once again: look at what the OP wrote, and look what you wrote. They literally provided zero code. Just a screenshot (and not of code). There's nothing to answer here (and definitely no need for a custom solution). Remember that Stack Overflow is not a "post requirements and receive custom code" site. It's for specific programming questions.

Comment: SiddheshDesai, thank you for your repeated responses.
I understand from your answer that you have edited "host.json" to add parallel processing.
However, I could not understand why it takes so long to start random_forest due to the heavy processing of Function.
Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @TY00 _ It is due to how Task Hub behaves - Given that the History size is mainly controlled by the number of Tasks, we can simplify this expression to be O(T^2), meaning that the time spent on replay increased quadratically in the number of Tasks. This cost isn’t really noticeable in small orchestrations, but it makes a huge difference if your orchestrator makes a lot of Activity calls.  Reference - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/durable-functions-for-python-just-got-faster/ba-p/2647246

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp#representation-in-storageAnd refer this MS Document to understand how Task Hub processes the message-